# Java loop or something

Tags: java

I've been experimenting and I want my `Exit` to recognize `yes` or `no`.

If I choose `yes` it will be all over, but if I choose `no` I want it to go back to the main.

Here is my experimentation:

```
public static void Exit() {
    String user;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Y  For yes");
    System.out.println("N  For No");
    System.out.print("\nAre you Sure you want to exit: ");
    user = in.nextLine();

    if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
        System.out.println("***Thank you for coming***");
    else if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
        switch(user) {
        case n:
            NewStudent();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "loop or something" is pretty to close to one possible solution. You could wrap your menu inside a `while (true) {}` block, and do a `System.exit(0)` when the user selects yes, but there are many more options. That said, your code does not follow Java coding conventions. Method names should by camelCased.

Comment: What do you want ? What is the problem ? Please see [ask] and post a [mcve]

Comment: What is exactly the problem here? It is not clear.

Comment: @aaron, please don't change the code proposed... you've add a closing bracket ... correcting one of the problem here (I have remove that part)

Comment: What is the purpose of that switch statement? What is the function you want to go back to?

Answer (score 0):

You miss a close bracket after if statement and also `""` for case `n`

```
public static void Exit() {

        String user;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Y  For yes");
        System.out.println("N  For No");
        System.out.print("\nAre you Sure you want to exit: ");
        user = in.nextLine();

          if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            System.out.println("***Thank you for coming***");
          } else if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                    NewStudent();
          }
       }
```

Since you are using if else, switch statement is not necessary in your code

Comment: You should explain a bit more the solution. Why `case n` is incorrect, why it is not needed, ...

Answer (score -1):

You can use "return" statement to exit from a method.

```
public static void Exit() {
     String user;
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Y  For yes");
     System.out.println("N  For No");
     System.out.print("\nAre you Sure you want to exit: ");
     user = in.nextLine();

     if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
         System.out.println("***Thank you for coming***");
     }
     else if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
          switch(user) {
    case n:
        NewStudent();
        //Exit from this method
        return;
    }
}
```

}